# how to save image on android in unity

Tags: c#, android, image, unity-game-engine

I'm new in Unity and I'm trying to save an image for get it after. I try Application.CaptureScreenshot and the method with Texture2D.ReadPixel, i try to save in persistentDataPath (/data/user/0/my.package.name/files/), in /sdcard/Download/ and in /storage/emulated/0/Download. No method worked. In every manifest of my project I have WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission. If I save to persistent data, I don't found it I found only cache of UnityAds, and if I save to Download folder I get access denied.

Anyone can help me?

Here's my code :

```
IEnumerator ScreenShot(){
         yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame ();
         Application.CaptureScreenshot ("ball.png");
         Application.CaptureScreenshot ("/sdcard/Download/ball.png");
         int width = Screen.width;
         int height = Screen.height;
         Texture2D tex = new Texture2D (width, height, TextureFormat.RGB24, false);
         tex.ReadPixels (new Rect (0, 0, width, height), 0, 0);
         tex.Apply ();
         byte[] bytes = tex.EncodeToJPG ();
         File.WriteAllBytes ("sdcard/Download/ball.png", bytes);
         File.WriteAllBytes (Application.persistentDataPath + "/ball.png", bytes);
 }
```

Before i check if folders exist :

```
if(!System.IO.Directory.Exists("/sdcard/Download/"))
{ 
    System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory ("/sdcard/Download/"); 
}

if(!System.IO.Directory.Exists(Application.persistentDataPath))
{
    System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory (Application.persistentDataPath);
}
```

And I start IEnumerator with:

```
StartCoroutine(ScreenShot());
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You sure it is not saving it? Have you tried to read the file at the path?

Comment: yes, i go to the path /Android/data/mypackge/ and there isn't files folder only cache of unityads, and in download folder there isn't too.

Comment: i thouht that the path isn't readable by user but if i share this image with both the path i return black screen and that the image isn't exist

Comment: CaptureScreenshot saves in Application.persistentDataPath. You can use it to retrieve the data with the name of the file.

Comment: ok, I try but is normal that i don't find manually in Android/data/mypackage/?

Comment: No luck, I've tried to share with 'Application.persistentDataPath + "/ball.png"' and  '"file://" + Application.persistentDataPath + "/ball.png"'

Comment: byte [] bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(Application.persistentDataPath + "/ball.png");

Comment: With this code i have java.lang.NoSuchMethodError :  `public IEnumerator ShareScreenshot()
 {
  isProcessing = true;

  yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();

  int width = Screen.width;
  int height = Screen.height;
  
  Texture2D tex = new Texture2D (width, height, TextureFormat.RGB24, true);
  
     tex.ReadPixels (new Rect (0, 0, width, height), 0, 0);
  
  tex.Apply ();
 
  byte[] bytes = tex.EncodeToPNG ();

  File.WriteAllBytes (Application.persistentDataPath + "/ball.png", bytes);
  byte[] image = File.ReadAllBytes (Application.persistentDataPath + "/ball.png");`

Comment: and i get it with : AndroidJavaObject uriObject = uriClass.CallStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("parse", image);

Comment: is it right?...Sorry for my little experience

Comment: Finally i run my app in an other phone (MOTOG3 Android 6.0) and it save the screenshot in the correct path (android/data/mypackage/files) and i found it, but the same apk on Nexus 5 with android 6.0.1 doesn't save the screenshot and i don't know why yet

Comment: Android 6 has brought us a lot of pain, tears and sorrow with Unity. Android 6 has changed a lot of things...

Comment: Yes..Thank you very much for the help!!!

Answer (score 1):

Here is what works for me:

```
    string destination = DateTime.Now.ToString ("yyyy-MM-dd-HHmmss") + ".png";
    string fullDestination = Path.Combine (Application.persistentDataPath, destination);

    Application.CaptureScreenshot (destination);

    SharingWriter.WriteTextInstant ("Preparing...");

    FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(fullDestination);
    while(fileInfo == null || fileInfo.Exists == false)
    {
        yield return null;
        fileInfo = new FileInfo(fullDestination);
    }
```

Application.CaptureScreenshot handles everything, no need to worry about reading pixels and writing to files that's redundant. Just have a while loop afterwards in the Coroutine to wait for the magic to happen! I used this to create screenshot sharing functionality for mobile.